# Tomcat is not starting in port 8443

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https, server.xml

I have hosted a website using apache server in a ubuntu VM in digitalocean. I want to configure SSL on Tomcat 8 on my backend url to make it HTTPS.

For that, I generated a .keystore and changed the server.xml file in the tomcat/config directory.
But when I loaded port 8443 along with my ip ( https://111.11.11.11:8443/ )it doesn't load. The port 8443 is not in the listening list in the server.

My server.xml file is as follws.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>


<Service name="Catalina">


<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />


<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
       disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
       keystoreFile="/home/sedsslweb/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="password"
       maxThreads="25" port="8443"
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>

 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
 </Realm>

 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```

Bacically what I want is to make the backend url https beacuse I can't send request from my **https** frontend url to bacekend **http** url beacause it is blocked because of the mixed content (Both frontend and backened must be whether https ot http).

I'm stuck in this issue for days and can anyone please help me to solve this isssue. Or atleast a alternative to make backend https.

Ps: In catalina.out I got this error.

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1077)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:557)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /opt/tomcat/tomcat.keystore (Permission denied)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:100)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:72)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:247)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1147)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:599)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1074)
```

Comment: Do you see the tomcat process running after you start the server?  Can you post any relevant information from your catalina.out and catalina.log files?  Show us the command you used to generate the keystore file?  How do you expect us to troubleshoot this without any information?

Comment: Also you created the keystore but what did you import into it?  Did you generate a CSR?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I updated the question. Can you please look into it.

Comment: What user and group owns tomcat and it's files?  What user and group owns the keystore?  Also what are the permission bit on the keystore? Can you try to `chmod 400 /opt/tomcat/tomcat.keystore`

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Thank you for your guide. It was a issue with the permission for the /opt/tomcat.

Comment: ok thats what I figured.  it was either file ownership/group or permission bits of either the keystore or tomcat files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed the permission of the /opt/tomcat directory and it works like a charm.

```
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat
```